# How to apply different security constraints for each method in Grails 3, using interceptors

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

Grails 3 introduced [Interceptors](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/guide/single.html#interceptors) to handle things like applying security constraints to various controller actions.

I have a `Thing` controller with a number of actions. These actions fall into three different groups, each of which requiring a different security role.

- `index`,`list`,`status` actions require role "viewer"
- `edit`,`save` action requires role "editor"
- `delete` actions require security role "admin"

I could implement this as three separate interceptors:

```
class ThingInterceptor1 {
    ThingInterceptor1(){
        match(controller:'thing', action:~/(index|list|status)/)
    }
    before() {
        verifyUserHasRole('viewer')
    }
}
class ThingInterceptor2 {
    ThingInterceptor1(){
        match(controller:'thing', action:~/(edit|save)/)
    }
    before() {
        verifyUserHasRole('editor')
    }
}
class ThingInterceptor3 {
    ThingInterceptor1(){
        match(controller:'thing', action:'delete')
    }
    before() {
        verifyUserHasRole('admin')
    }
}
```

I have a lot of controllers like this, so **ideally, I'd like to apply all these constraints in a single interceptor**, like this:

```
class ThingInterceptor {
    ThingInterceptor(){
        match(controller:'thing', action:~/(index|list|status)/)
        match(controller:'thing', action:~/(edit|save)/)
        match(controller:'thing', action:'delete')
    }
    ...
```

But how would I determine the action name inside the `before` method? I'm looking for something like this:

```
before() {
    def actionName = ????
    if(actionName.matches(~/(index|list|status)/)){
        verifyUserHasRole('viewer')
    }
    else if(actionName.matches(~/(edit|save)/){
        verifyUserHasRole('editor')
    }
    else if(actionName == 'delete'){
        verifyUserHasRole('admin')
    }
}
```

**Is there any way to accomplish this in a single interceptor, or do I have to split this into three different interceptors, one for each group of actions?**

Comment: Hmm. Why the downvote?

Comment: On the method `before()`, you can access to thoses variables `actionName` (which tells you the action called by the user) and `controllerName` (which tells you the controller called). For example, you can do something like that: `log.info("Current action: $actionName on the controller: $controllerName")`

Comment: Thanks. Is that documented somewhere? I couldn't find that mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Joch pointed out, you can get the action name via `actionName`, but that doesn't seem to be documented anywhere for Interceptors.